# caja (Mate file manager) plugin for meld?

Tags: mate, caja, meld

Does someone is able to convert the caja meld plugin to become compatible with Ubuntu Mate 20.04? That is a very important plugin for me, beside the open as admin .....

An old one is here:
http://www.giuspen.com/software/cajapyext/meld-compare.py

Thanks a million.

Comment: It looks like you mean http://www.giuspen.com/software/cajapyext/meld-compare.py .

Comment: Yes, correct - sorry - I have changed that.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend to contact Giuspen directly about you need.

Below are two alternatives:

- Other possibility is to use [shell alternative](https://gist.github.com/N0rbert/b0b11340e588b33fab542b0c72837e41), I can share it with you:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install meld

  mkdir -p ~/.config/caja/scripts
  cd ~/.config/caja/scripts
  wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/N0rbert/b0b11340e588b33fab542b0c72837e41/raw/6ec7f6ccea71ac3d473038c4ae66041494a24688/meld
  chmod +x meld
  ```

  it will be available in Caja when you have selected 2-3 files or 2-3 folders: *File* → *Scripts* → *meld* . See screenshots:

  1. [single pane operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfHbh.png)
  2. [dual pane operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R2mm.png) (<kbd>F3</kbd>, *View* → *Extra Pane*)
- As temporary substitution you can try to configure custom action using Caja Actions Configuration Tool from `caja-actions` package.

Comment: I found this is an almost sufficient solution. Thank you! That helps me a lot. If you allow me a comment - at the momemt I just see two drawbacks: 1) I can't select two files in separate steps (if there are in different folders as for instance) and 2) I need another step to open the script folder. The second isn't a real problem. But calling the script with a single file/folder should activate a kind of memory. And if there is something in the memory the next call of the script should ask for being the initial comparision file or (more likely) the one to be compared with that in memory.

Comment: The "1)" is solvable by using <F3> (Extra Pane). I'm using this script last 5 years without problems for files and directories :)

Comment: Thanks, with this addition it can be a solution. Thank you so much. If you ever found it useful to add a "memory" as mentioned to your script - please let me know. :)

Comment: @N0rbert thanks a lot for your script. I modified it to remember the last selected file (if only one is selected) and use it to call meld if then another single file is selected, so that it works while browsing thru different folders or when using two separate caja windows. I guess it could be split in two scripts (one for choosing ons file at a time and other for multiple files at once). You can find it here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mariovaldez/99f40cdd74e9c4e638cf62ae45d47833/raw/93e8272e878b27b0e0c4f7ec7012fffcb42d610b/meld